# use regex on filename/filepath for FileInputStream

Tags: regex, filenames, fileinputstream

How to use Regex on file names for FileInputStream. i.e. how to pick the files with name abc*.txt by using FileInputStream. When I used as below it throws fileIOexception.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/dir1/dir2/abc.*\\.txt");
```

Comment: Generally you will get many files that have name matching regex, so its logical that `FileInputStream()` accept a specefic filename and doesnt accept regex.

Comment: what if want to read 0 or more files? What is the regular expression if wanted to access only one file with name abc*.txt like abc123.txt or abc234.txt

Comment: If we imagine that `FileInputStream()` read 0 or more files, how you will use it ? how to know which file you are dealing with now ? just think about how to use it.

Comment: @54l3d: you are right. If I dont know the exact file name, how to generalize the file name in fileinputstream?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use [PathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html). Here is the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html).

Example:

```
String pattern = "glob:*.{java,class}";
PathMatcher matcher =
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(pattern);
```